# Error in sum using dplyr::summarise (but fixable using rounding)

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding

I have been using dplyr::summarise to sum daily data by month and have just spent a few hours finally figuring out that for whatever reason the decimal places in my raw data was throwing the function off.

Basically, the monthly sums for 'temp1' (which is the 'Mod' data) are wrong (the digits look right but the decimal place is in the wrong place) until I apply a rounding function (rounded to 7 or less digits fixes the problem it seems, 8 just reproduces the problem)

```
temp1 <- as.data.frame(read.csv("data/ModObs.csv"))
temp1$Date <- as.Date(temp1$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
((((temp1$Obs <- round(temp1$Obs, 7))))#this line fixes the problem
((((temp1$Mod <- round(temp1$Mod, 7))))#this line fixes the problem
temp1$yearmonth <- lubridate::floor_date(as.Date(temp1$Date), 'month')
temp2 <- dplyr::group_by(temp1, yearmonth)
temp2 <- dplyr::summarise(temp2, Obs = sum(Obs, na.rm=TRUE))
temp1 <- dplyr::group_by(temp1, yearmonth)
temp1 <- dplyr::summarise(temp1, Mod = sum(Mod, na.rm=TRUE))
```

My question is, is there a way of using dplyr::summarise that means I would not have encountered this issue (which took me quite a while to figure out and solve)?

dput with error:

> dput(temp1)
> structure(list(yearmonth = structure(c(0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151,
> 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365, 396, 424, 455, 485, 516, 546,
> 577, 608, 638, 669, 699, 730, 761, 790, 821, 851, 882, 912, 943,
> 974, 1004, 1035, 1065, 1096, 1127, 1155, 1186, 1216, 1247, 1277,
> 1308, 1339, 1369, 1400, 1430, 1461, 1492, 1520, 1551, 1581, 1612,
> 1642, 1673, 1704, 1734, 1765, 1795, 1826, 1857, 1885, 1916, 1946,
> 1977, 2007, 2038, 2069, 2099, 2130, 2160, 2191, 2222, 2251, 2282,
> 2312, 2343, 2373, 2404, 2435, 2465, 2496, 2526, 2557, 2588, 2616,
> 2647, 2677, 2708, 2738, 2769, 2800, 2830, 2861, 2891, 2922, 2953,
> 2981, 3012, 3042, 3073, 3103, 3134, 3165, 3195, 3226, 3256, 3287,
> 3318, 3346, 3377, 3407, 3438, 3468, 3499, 3530, 3560, 3591, 3621,
> 3652, 3683, 3712, 3743, 3773, 3804, 3834, 3865, 3896, 3926, 3957,
> 3987, 4018, 4049, 4077, 4108, 4138, 4169, 4199, 4230, 4261, 4291,
> 4322, 4352, 4383, 4414, 4442, 4473, 4503, 4534, 4564, 4595, 4626,
> 4656, 4687, 4717, 4748, 4779, 4807, 4838, 4868, 4899, 4929, 4960,
> 4991, 5021, 5052, 5082, 5113, 5144, 5173, 5204, 5234, 5265, 5295,
> 5326, 5357, 5387, 5418, 5448, 5479, 5510, 5538, 5569, 5599, 5630,
> 5660, 5691, 5722, 5752, 5783, 5813, 5844, 5875, 5903, 5934, 5964,
> 5995, 6025, 6056, 6087, 6117, 6148, 6178, 6209, 6240, 6268, 6299,
> 6329, 6360, 6390, 6421, 6452, 6482, 6513, 6543, 6574, 6605, 6634,
> 6665, 6695, 6726, 6756, 6787, 6818, 6848, 6879, 6909, 6940, 6971,
> 6999, 7030, 7060, 7091, 7121, 7152, 7183, 7213, 7244, 7274), class = "Date"),
> Obs = c(29.5, 1.6, 225.9, 305, 485.9, 392.6, 86.7, 422.1,
> 262.6, 22.6, 12.7, 40.3, 96.5, 1.4, 0, 40.1, 251.9, 494.4,
> 181.6, 86, 69.6, 128.4, 560.9, 55.8, 14.2, 94.1, 8.9, 28.2,
> 10.3, 1.4, 2.6, 9, 14.2, 5.6, 9.5, 1.6, 0, 195.1, 24.3, 18.9,
> 26, 34.3, 68.1, 144.1, 213.3, 99.2, 36.1, 17, 19.5, 13.3,
> 0, 352.7, 2812.7, 82, 311.9, 314.2, 397.5, 783.7, 388.7,
> 40.4, 1.3, 0, 2.1, 2.9, 2.1, 8.6, 1.2, 260.8, 494.4, 1125.1,
> 983.3, 20.9, 3.2, 0, 0.1, 1.1, 0.6, 32.9, 16.2, 124.1, 204.3,
> 340.6, 212.6, 42.8, 56.7, 2.2, 22.6, 78.3, 100.2, 786.4,
> 990.7, 330.2, 119.9, 2.7, 3.5, 5.7, 9.4, 17.6, 104.2, 168.9,
> 43, 118.4, 69.7, 479.3, 435.4, 101.4, 52.9, 104, 28.6, 0.8,
> 1.8, 13.1, 54.4, 26.2, 6.3, 24.8, 30.7, 53.9, 1.4, 0, 4.6,
> 0, 1.5, 14.5, 67.3, 217.4, 460.5, 251.2, 72.3, 29.3, 57.7,
> 29.7, 1.4, 1, 30.4, 3.6, 164.2, 378.4, 861.1, 982.5, 116.5,
> 68.4, 33.9, 1.5, 52.3, 7.5, 18.2, 70.4, 75.9, 158.9, 26.1,
> 2.3, 6, 8.4, 0.1, 43.9, 8.3, 0, 0.7, 8.6, 38.3, 24.2, 110.1,
> 164.1, 239, 120.8, 23.9, 24.7, 1.8, 1.4, 54.7, 75.6, 11.6,
> 19.6, 69.4, 199.7, 648.3, 260.9, 53.5, 4.5, 0.5, 0, 0.6,
> 60.9, 9, 130.9, 61.7, 539.5, 222.1, 31.6, 19.8, 288.6, 83.3,
> 2, 1.8, 104.4, 214, 108.3, 504.2, 152.6, 110.2, 103.3, 14.7,
> 128.2, 3.5, 2.5, 7.2, 47.4, 73.6, 116.2, 150.6, 161.1, 58.8,
> 32.9, 12.1, 33.3, 31.3, 0.7, 39.7, 0.3, 26, 102.2, 55.2,
> 46.3, 62.3, 15.4, 200.2, 98.9, 35.5, 0.4, 80.3, 286.5, 348.8,
> 646.5, 340.3, 1048.5, 558.6, 365.5, 129.4, 3.7), Mod = c(58.456732574,
> 0.647399496, 106.77816386, 267.838017351, 599.939323463,
> 250.80934844, 113.281660213, 241.663996002, 127.530387061,
> 52.687410089, 84.890244021, 41.364802773, 59.23208781, 8.497558874,
> 0.672761812, 15.465132304, 358.926445816, 399.9093607, 97.971842098,
> 42.72450411, 78.475537521, 267.696647395, 1499.730009232,
> 164.134543701, 15.739950594, 117.176571603, 0.29960511, 33.153451885,
> 71.35707594, 1.976493212, 38.99406048, 58.699745671, 88.893788732,
> 55.590919209, 17.675911123, 0.323688533, 0.802922429, 255.339027286,
> 86.973361482, 56.672316286, 195.494804037, 113.402888496,
> 88.016557451, 146.313739207, 141.11162499, 309.49712486,
> 42.342303882, 32.801816137, 9.804984811, 14.876734504, 0.741273571,
> 432.148407136, 2516.875488309, 47.539316029, 269.405152962,
> 183.64372206, 154.563624943, 467.720012557, 153.054373772,
> 32.514885627, 1.830055421, 0.066762771, 1.044433442, 1.346976081,
> 17.458179607, 49.907434727, 53.305731876, 353.57856375, 310.529543548,
> 962.398015832, 344.181844335, 30.810939684, 8.040785393,
> 0.377896164, 0.798674902, 0.801987649, 0.691369382, 13.928109124,
> 12.703685263, 137.85141766, 211.000002457, 444.374773665,
> 187.06473363, 56.579158088, 79.307114494, 1.185915374, 7.450495202,
> 350.92445957, 168.333585374, 1103.415013415, 530.738230571,
> 97.400577403, 120.218466778, 26.53863178, 4.95759286, 1.415953207,
> 1.349259407, 7.598631896, 31.687964985, 111.63067543, 253.033200389,
> 260.084267318, 174.328538378, 435.075601539, 266.057507136,
> 169.491413576, 370.501536962, 325.734910145, 52.804905885,
> 0.637640491, 0.749393501, 61.044014158, 236.352010674, 69.236802018,
> 50.981912279, 113.755615714, 68.015519965, 228.376481539,
> 1.35494224, 0.370446501, 1.782754512, 0.200525121, 0.567715904,
> 2.562157517, 66.360280078, 537.409598471, 548.857756317,
> 131.818783821, 79.38907511, 216.219977069, 86.85853468, 91.042441797,
> 1.310072508, 4.6784498, 49.359916771, 12.139100379, 792.36086926,
> 360.543361637, 674.819587278, 417.14625705, 71.213853069,
> 88.470327459, 26.501678301, 0.660446628, 1.983262203, 0.053393889,
> 2.116900185, 103.974625465, 146.1406309, 241.456322328, 41.761031962,
> 19.165518836, 61.329157567, 77.461701504, 0.717057613, 60.244865985,
> 2.038796249, 0.024612503, 1.15999722, 0.987871135, 66.752973657,
> 101.602951298, 207.507552152, 351.874694806, 239.490966404,
> 373.402963887, 83.392418938, 96.713198206, 2.471314963, 1.789748376,
> 23.642411238, 274.437164678, 27.196302352, 122.879115856,
> 203.243972815, 261.450286079, 674.337097864, 201.592587766,
> 66.457305017, 14.265446489, 11.688820111, 0.287104024, 0.498545345,
> 10.595714786, 64.36811409, 147.944544256, 105.263660789,
> 348.781394762, 115.965911604, 81.556952547, 35.877763907,
> 293.156577573, 122.052605838, 0.891615203, 0.201455399, 17.693507458,
> 191.862026713, 93.030313466, 379.074639489, 88.590763754,
> 138.225716958, 438.407332197, 11.107850781, 175.835916749,
> 0.793580574, 0.755295219, 1.253581528, 2.175241521, 126.829190302,
> 167.624256025, 261.538659971, 143.633607733, 58.216055381,
> 101.857571372, 37.192461414, 112.344312062, 100.262190061,
> 2.378722279, 4.946631624, 0.435401092, 51.481605801, 155.384067186,
> 153.115869623, 128.316180053, 153.07003862, 80.585921934,
> 221.89445498, 62.047224666, 105.157734971, 0.203008456, 51.168132113,
> 310.567488885, 238.329914336, 783.724869869, 193.016695288,
> 431.815627948, 143.854730373, 358.082995503, 84.620059176,
> 1.146042245)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
> -240L))

Comment: Have you read [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) (pdf)? It is a good introduction to floating point errors in R. I haven't looked closely at your code but it sounds like that's what this is.

Comment: to share your data, just run `dput(temp1)` and paste the results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is exactly the same before and after the rounding.

```
library(dplyr)
temp1 <- as.data.frame(read.csv("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/modops.csv"))
temp1$Date <- as.Date(temp1$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
temp1$yearmonth <- lubridate::floor_date(as.Date(temp1$Date), 'month')
notfixed <- dplyr::group_by(temp1, yearmonth) %>% summarise(Mod = sum(Mod, na.rm=TRUE))
temp1$Obs <- round(temp1$Obs, 7)#this line fixes the problem
fixed <- dplyr::group_by(temp1, yearmonth) %>% summarise(Mod = sum(Mod, na.rm=TRUE))
> identical(fixed, notfixed)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Maybe related to how I put my data into the question... but mine is definitely not identical. I will post some screenshots.

Comment: don't post sceenshots. use `dput(temp1)` instead

Comment: I have the same result with your newly shared data.

Comment: Ok thanks if its not reproducible it must be something I'm missing so I'll keep looking appreciate the help